# How to solve Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, laravel

I have main table Tickets with a foreign key to another table called ticket_statuses. I want to get display the status field from ticket_statuses according to foreign key.

**TicketsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Users;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Ticket;
use App\TicketStatus;
use App\Models\User;
etc...

class TicketsController extends UserController
{

public function index()
{
    $tickets = Ticket::paginate(25);

    return view('user.tickets.index', compact('tickets'));
}

}
```

Ticket.php

```
class Ticket extends Model
{

    // Ticket __belongs_to__ User
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function ticketstatus()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TicketStatus');
    }



}
```

TicketStatus.php

```
class TicketStatus extends Model
{
    // Ticket Status __has_many__ Ticket
    public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Ticket');
    }

}
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach($tickets as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $item->ticket_statuses->status }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->customer }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->user->first_name }} {{ $item->user->last_name }}</td>
        <td>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I am getting error because of the line {{ $item->ticket_statuses->status  }} . I also tried {{ $item->ticketstatus->status  }} The error is **Trying to get property of non-object**

Please help. Thanks

Comment: What are the column names in your `tickets` table ?

Comment: id, subject, customer_id, user_id, _ticket_status_id

Comment: Check my answer below. I think it's `_ticket_status_id` which causing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in comments, change

```
public function ticketstatus()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\TicketStatus');
}
```

to

```
public function ticketstatus()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\TicketStatus', '_ticket_status_id', 'id');
}
```

And then try again with `{{ $item->ticketstatus->status }}`. By relation laravel is looking for `ticket_status_id` column in your `tickets` table while you are using `_ticket_status_id`

Let us know if it helps or not.

Comment: @mahfuzuk  I just got back because I was assigned to another Project. But I really Praise you for your greatness. You're a guru.

Answer (score 1):

If your `$item` might not have a ticket_statuses, you might want to do a check before displaying them.

```
<td>{{ isset($item->ticketstatus) ? $item->ticket_statuses->status  : '' }}</td>
```

or with Laravel Blade shorthand

```
<td>{{ $item->ticketstatus->status or "default message" }}</td>
```

Comment: i'm not getting any values because of <td>{{ isset($item->ticket_statuses) ? $item->ticket_statuses->status  : '' }}</td>.. hmmm..

Comment: can you try using $item->ticketstatus? if still doesnt work, try dd($item) and show us

Answer (score 1):

Your relation name in Ticket model is ticketstatus,and you are trying to get data using ticket_statuses,what is completely wrong,try to use your relation name,like below

```
$item->ticketstatus->status
```

Comment: Hi. $item->ticketstatus->status is still wrong.. i wonder i still need to extend via controller

Comment: may be your keep wrong foreign key in ticketStatus table.What foreign key you use in ticketstatus table?